# My variables don't assign properly when being passed through different functions in C

Tags: c

I'm making a program for a school project that calculates the size of a room and calculates the prices for paint, labour etc. This function is where the user enters the dimensions of the room. The variables seem not to assign properly. in the main function i put `&` next to the variables in the parameters and added the `*`s here in this function however this did not fix the program i ended up getting an error saying :

> [Error] invalid operands to binary <= (have 'float *' and 'double')

```
 float areaInput(float* height, float* width, float* length)                   /*recieve pointer value in c function*/
{

    do{
        printf("Please enter the height of the room in metres: ");
        scanf("%f", &height);
        emptyBuffer();
        if (height <= 2.0 || height >= 4.6)
        {
            printf("Please enter a value between 2.1 - 4.5 metres\n");
        }
    }while(height <= 2.0 || height >= 4.6);

    do{
        printf("Please enter the width of the room in metres: ");
        scanf("%f", &width);
        emptyBuffer();
        if (width <= 1.74 || width >= 8.21)
        {
            printf("Please enter a value between 1.75 - 8.2 metres\n");
        }
    }while(width <= 1.74 || width >= 8.21);

    do{
        printf("Please enter the length of the room in metres: ");
        scanf("%f", &length);
        emptyBuffer();
        if (length <= 1.74 || length >= 8.21)
        {
            printf("Please enter a value between 1.75 - 8.2 metres\n");
        }
    }while(length <= 1.74 || length >= 8.21);

}
```

Comment: Except for the function prototype and the `scanf`, change all `height` to `*height` (it's a _pointer_ to a value and _not_ a value). Do the same for `width` and `length`. You want (e.g.) `if (*height < 2.0 || *height >= 4.6)` In `scanf`, change `&height` to `height`

Comment: you're doing `printf; scanf; emptyBuffer; if (length <= 1.74 || length >= 8.21)` again and again which is not good. And for such a simple purpose, writing it in a scripting language (if you know one) will be a lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the parameters are pointers, you need to dereference them with `*` to access the values. You also don't need to use `&` when calling `scanf()`, because it expects a pointer to the location to store the input and that's what the variable is.

And instead of doing the same range test in both the `if` and `do-while`, you can simply use `break` whenthe `if` fails.

```
float areaInput(float* height, float* width, float* length) /*recieve pointer value in c function*/
{
    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter the height of the room in metres: ");
        scanf("%f", height);
        emptyBuffer();
        if (*height <= 2.0 || *height >= 4.6) {
            printf("Please enter a value between 2.1 - 4.5 metres\n");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter the width of the room in metres: ");
        scanf("%f", width);
        emptyBuffer();
        if (*width <= 1.74 || *width >= 8.21) {
            printf("Please enter a value between 1.75 - 8.2 metres\n");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter the length of the room in metres: ");
        scanf("%f", length);
        emptyBuffer();
        if (*length <= 1.74 || *length >= 8.21) {
            printf("Please enter a value between 1.75 - 8.2 metres\n");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, your input validation messages don't match what you're testing. If the user enters height `2.05` it will be allowed, even though it's not between `2.1` and `4.5`. You're assuming that the user will only enter 1 digit after the decimal point, and also not accounting for the fact that floating point has errors for many decimal fractions. Use `< 2.1` instead of `<= 2.0`, for instance.